# Get DOM element exact position recursively including parent rotations and translations

Tags: javascript, html, css, matrix, homogenous-transformation

**Context**

I'm trying to create a formula that allow me to get the exact position of a DOM element in the highest ancestor landmark. There are some specific rules in my probleme. Each element are absolute positionned and all element have a known top and left value in pixels. Each element can also have a rotation transform with a known value in degres. The rotation transform is also performed from the top left corner of the element.

To make it more understandable there is an exemple as an image just below.

[image]

In this exemple we have an arborescence composed of 3 elements. The element C is child of element B and element B is child of element A. To make it as simple as possible consider those 3 elements as simple `<div>` tag. Each of these elements have a known position and rotation angle in the parent landmark.

**The probleme**

I know the top and left value of each div element in its direct parent landmark. But i want to find the top left corner position of the element C in the general landmark representated as the landmark of the element A.

To achieve that i used homogenous transformation matrix. I calculate the general transform matrix of each element combining the translation and rotation matrix.

The rotation matrix of an element explained as :

[image]

With t the angle in radient of a given element in its parent landmark.

The translation matrix of an element explained as :

[image]

With top, left respectively the offset of the element from its parent origin top left corner.

Let's call `Mr.x` the rotation matrix of the element x.

Let's call `Mt.x` the translation matrix of the element x.

Let's call `Mg.x` the global transformation matrix of the element x. Obtained by doing `Mr.x * Mt.x`.

Let's call `Cx.y` the coordinates of the top left element x in the y element landmark.

**The calcul**

So i know `Cc.b`, `Cb.a` and `Ca.g` with g the general landmark. And i want `Cc.g` or the coordinates of the top left of element C in the general landmark.

So what i first did is accumulating all the transformation matrix of all parents elements starting with a 3 dimensions identity matrix. let's call this matrix `Gtm` for general transformation matrix.

The calcul is :

Gtm = Gtm * Mg.a

Gtm = Gtm * Mg.b

Then i create a "homogenous" point with the offset of the element C in the element B like below:

p = (6, 1.5, 0)

Then i multiply my point with the general transform matrix Gtm to get this point in the general landmark.

point = p * Gtm.

But that given point isn't correct and isn't integrating all the offsets of the parent correctly i don't get the correct coordinates and i don't know what i'm missing on here.

Sorry my Math and representations are approximatives. Ask me anything to get more informations if i'm not clear enough. And thank for any time spent on this.

**Edit 1**

Consider a Js object which a reference to a dom element and a reference to it's parent object.

```
let elA = {
  DOM_element = /* The <div> A */
  parent = null;
}
let elB = {
  DOM_element = /* The <div> B */
  parent = elA;
}
let elC = {
  DOM_element = /* The <div> C */
  parent = elB;
}
```

Consider that each of these objects have three methods respectively called `getTranslationMatrix`, `getRotationMatrix`, and `getTransformMatrix`, and that each of these objects have an attribute named `rotation` with a rotation value in **degree**

The code :

```
  /**
  * Get the translation matrix of the element 
  */
  getTranslationMatrix() {
    // Create the translation matrix of the element
    let translationMatrix = matrix([
      [1, 0, this.DOM_element.offsetLeft],
      [0, 1, this.DOM_element.offsetTop],
      [0, 0, 1],
    ]);

    return translationMatrix;
  }

  /**
  * Get the rotation matrix of the element 
  */
  getRotationMatrix() {
    // Create the rotation matrix of the element
    let rotationMatrix = matrix([
      [Math.cos(this.rotation * (Math.PI/180)), Math.sin(this.rotation * (Math.PI/180)), 0],
      [-Math.sin(this.rotation * (Math.PI/180)), Math.cos(this.rotation * (Math.PI/180)), 0],
      [0, 0, 1],
    ]);

    return rotationMatrix;
  }

  /**
  * Get the transform matrix of the element 
  */
  getTransformMatrix() {
    // Multiply all transform matrixes
    return multiply(this.getRotationMatrix(), this.getTranslationMatrix());
  }
```

`matrix` and `multiply` are fonctions provided by the mathjs library.

Now the code executed in the object elC :

```
// Get the reversed context stack
    let contextStack = [];
    let context = this.parent;
    while(context) {
      contextStack.unshift(context);
      context = context.parent;
    }

    // Create the transform matrix
    let transformMatrix = matrix([
      [1, 0, 0],
      [0, 1, 0],
      [0, 0, 1]
    ]);
    contextStack.forEach(context => {
      transformMatrix = multiply(context.getTransformMatrix(), transformMatrix);
    });

    // Create the origin point
    let origin = [
      this.DOM_element.offsetLeft,
      this.DOM_element.offsetTop,
      1
    ];

    // Apply the transform matrix
    origin = multiply(origin, transformMatrix);
```

And i should get the correct coordinates in the origin point but that is not the case.

Comment: Want to add a runnable snippet that shows off one of the configurations you're working with, with the code you already wrote so far and a description of where things stop working? Also if you can, get someone to help improve this machine translation, because it's hard to understand what you're asking, since you're not using the right terms for the things you're asking about.

Comment: It's gonna be very hard to put some replicable code because i'm working on a heavy webbased software but i'll try to add the code i'm using to do the matrix transformation part in an edit

Comment: The trick here is usually to just make up an example, not "show all your code". A snippet with three nested divs, each with their own transform CSS should work just fine. Also, you may not be aware that you can actually get an element's transform matrix by just asking for it using `getComputersStyle(element).transform`, which drastically simplifies this problem. Recursively get all the matrices for an element and its ancestors, then matrix multiply them.

Comment: I'm working on a snippet. The problem with getComputedStyle is that i want to get the position of my element in any parent landmark. By the way is getComputedStyle... . transform giving only a mtrix resulting of the transforms of the parents element are also based on their positions ?

Comment: In that case, hopefully your snippet can show what you're actually doing (but remember to rewrite your post to still be a self-contained post, no "edit" sections; that's only for answers that need to be updated because time passed and answers changed/new APIs were added etc). Just rewrite your post to be able the code you're showing, so that folks can immediately understand the specific situation.

Comment: That said: the computed transform takes `top` and `left` into account. So both `{ top: 2em; left: 2em; transform: rotate(30deg)`  and `{ transform: translate(2em, 2em) rotate(30deg)` give the exact same `matrix(0.544639, 0.838671, -0.838671, 0.544639, 24, 12)` as the element's computed style transform matrix. So I'm pretty sure you can use that just fine. The only "trick" is to remember that the values are encoded as `[a,b,c,d,tx,ty]` even though for matrix multiplication you need to rewrite that to `[[a,b,tx],[c,d,ty],[0,0,1]]` form.

Comment: Ok i see. Thank for your precisions and time. One last question, i suppose that in a context where all elements are not absolute positionned but are just in the normal flow of there parent and then undergo the margins or the flex display for exemple of the parent the getComputedStyle.... . transform will not be based on the offsetWidth and offsetheight of the element in its parent ?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware, but you'll probably want to give that a quick test.

Comment: Just tested it and that's not working

Comment: You can get there 99% of the way using the transform attribute, after that we can exploit the bounding client rect, let me write up an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

We can get the combined rotation matrix by using the [computed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) `transform` property for the "c" element and all its ancestors, and then [matrix multiplying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) those (bearing in mind that CSS uses [homogeneous coordinate notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix) rather than specifying the 2D RT matrix as a 3x3 matrix the way we normally do when we need to perform linear algebra).

This gets us to the total rotation, plus a translation that's "wrong", but that we're going to set to zero anyway, because we can get the true translation we need by using [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

The takes box "c" and calculates what the corresponding absolute transform should be, and overlays a new div "d" (absolutely positioned wrt the page itself) on top of "c". In this snippet, "c" has been given a bright red background, "d" has been given a faint, transparent blue background, and so if all went well, you should see "d" overlaid on "c" with a purplish colour.

Also note that the tops of each box have been highlight in pink, to highlight the applied rotations.

```js
// Make sure "d" has the same dimensions as "c"
const cstyle = getComputedStyle(c);
const h = parseFloat(cstyle.height);
const w = parseFloat(cstyle.width);
d.style.height = `${h}px`;
d.style.width = `${w}px`;

// Then, align "d" to "c" using their center points.
const bbox = c.getBoundingClientRect();
const cy = bbox.top + bbox.height/2;
const cx = bbox.left + bbox.width/2;
d.style.top = `${cy - h/2}px`;
d.style.left = `${cx - w/2}px`;

// And finally, compute the total rotation, strip
// the translation, and apply that total rotation to "d".
const fullMatrix = getFullMatrix(c);
fullMatrix.e = fullMatrix.f = 0;
d.style.transform = fullMatrix;

function getFullMatrix(element) {
  if (!element) return new DOMMatrix();
  const css = getComputedStyle(element).transform;
  const matrix = new DOMMatrix(css);
  return getFullMatrix(element.offsetParent).multiply(matrix);
}
```

```css
div {
  border-top: 2px solid magenta;
}

#a {
  position:relative;
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 10em;
  height: 7em;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

#b {
  position:absolute;
  background: grey;
  width: 5em;
  height: 3em;
  top: 2em;
  left: 2em;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}


#c {
  width: 2.2em;
  height: 1.8em;
  background: red;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(1.5em, 0.75em) rotate(127deg);
}

#d {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0,0,250,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">
    <div id="c"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="d"></div>
```

Note that we can of course also just compute the rotation matrices by using a slice(0,4) and computing multiplication of the 2x2 rotation matrices, but that's frankly a premature optimization (and we'll still need to set add the 0 translation terms). We can always pare things down later if needed.

Also note that IEEE floating point numbers are *not* our friend, and the limited decimal places of the rotation matrix, as well as fractional pixel values for bounding boxes, means that we might be half a pixel off, which can get rendered as being an entire pixel off. This is, unfortunately, a consequence of the medium. If we wanted the *true* angle and offset, then really we should be using CSS variables so we can work directly with the numbers that define our layout instead of working backwards.

For example:

```
:root {
  --px-per-em: 16;
}

div {
  --x: 0;
  --y: 0;
  --angle: 0;
  --rotation: calc(1deg * var(--angle));
  transform:
    translate(calc(1px * var(--x)), calc(1px * var(--y)))
    rotate(var(--rotation));
}

#a {
  ...
}

#b {
  --angle: 30;
  ...
}


#c {
  --x: calc(1.5 * var(--px-per-em));
  --y: calc(0.75 * var(--px-per-em));
  --angle: 127;
  ...
}
```

We can now use `` getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue(`--angle`) | 0; `` (with the same type of recursion) to get the true total angle we're using, rather than working our way back through a bunch of matrix multiplications.

Comment: You could avoid some iterations by looking at `element.offsetParent` instead of `element.parentNode`. Also, no need to write your own CSS parser, matrix multiplier and CSS stringifier, `DOMMatrix` does it all on its own out of the box: https://jsfiddle.net/r2j7w6on/

Comment: Nice, updated for `offsetParent`. CSS wise, parsing/templating is little effort, but [DOMMatrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix) does look handy here. Just note that it's not technically formally a real thing yet, it's still in draft/CR stage for now.

Comment: (also somewhat disappointingly it appears to be heavily under-documented on MDN, so definitely have a look at Kaiido's fiddle, but it may be harder to find docs for how to use it -outside this use case- than most web APIs)

Comment: No, no, DOMMatrix is stable. W3C's "draft standards" are the equivalent of WHATWG "live". Everything that's not "draft" is actually possibly outdated. As for the docs, yes it's a bit unfortunate that not all methods have their own page yet, but you still have the small excerpt (doesn't help that it also spans to DOMMtrixInit though). If I get time someday I may chime in to improve these but it's honestly quite navigable already.

Comment: I thought only TR were considered "stable"? Still, good to hear.

Comment: TR are "stuck in time", so they don't necessarily reflect the truth of the current implementations. EDs should reflect the current implementations and that's why MDN and WHATWG generally link to EDs instead of TRs. But anyway, `DOMMatrix` is stable since quite  a long time, [here is the current TR](https://www.w3.org/TR/geometry-1/).

Comment: Gotcha, that's good to know! Answer updated.

Comment: Some update. I fixed my result problems using DOMMatrix. Thank to introduce me into this because i didn't know the existence of DOMMatrix API and that's quite cool and easy to use. That simplified a lot my calculations and make everything working good !